# New to PyCharm; Error opening FireFix webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm, I used Jupyter notebooks/Anaconda's Spyder a lot to test various website. Now I would like to make more of a standard framework out of it. And I would to use PyCharm to do this, because it looks it make live a lot easier with importing classes etc. But when I started to refactor my code and execute it. It wasn't able to open a simple webpage. Probably I'm missing something stupid, but could you help me out here? I slimmed down the code, to see why this is happening:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox

driver.get("https://www.google.nl/")
```

Error:

```
=================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________ ERROR collecting test_section.py _______________________
test_section.py:5: in <module>
    driver.get("https://www.google.nl/")
E   TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 1.25 seconds ===========================
Process finished with exit code 0
```

As far as I know the initial parameter is not mandatory.

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi Murthi, I'm using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox
driver.get('https://www.google.nl/')
```

That's assuming that you already have the Firefox driver added to your PATH (if you're on windows that is) if not I can edit to add in how to do that

### Gecko Driver in PATH

For this section you need to download the geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

once that is downloaded you need to unzip and place the .exe in a location that you will leave it in. After that open search in windows and search for *"view advanced system settings"*, under the advanced tab you will see at the bottom an option called *"Environment Variables"* click into this and it will load your PATH settings.

In this new tab there will be a bottom and a top half, you can ignore the top half and just focus on the bottom for now. find where it says "Path" on the left hand side and then click edit at the bottom. A new window will appear, from here click new, which will add a new line to the variable, and then paste in the **full** directory location, ie. C\Users\Documents\pathToGeckoDriver

Once that is done you can then restart your machine for it to take affect, and if done correctly you should be able to launch your program now.

Comment: I changed the code and I do receive an error now that the geckodriver executeble needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Edited my answer to include how to get PATH updated for geckodriver

Comment: Much appreciated! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

or

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```